# Best way to structure my shopping database?

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-design, relational-database

Right now my database has the following (simplified) format:

```
ShoppingList
{
     List<ListProduct> listProducts
}

ListProduct
{
    int quantity
    Product product
}

Product

{
     information about the overall product...
     List<StoreProduct> StoreProduct

}

StoreProduct

{
     information about the specific product and the store
}
```

In general, a **shoppinglist** contains a list of **listproducts** which each contains their quantity and their **product** which each contains a list of **storeproducts**.

This all works great - however, in my shoppinglist I wanna keep track of which storeproducts were purchased. Now I can't just add a "purchased" boolean to my storeproducts since they are used across multiple shopping lists (static information).

I thought of adding a purchasedProduct property of ListProduct which would be set to the purchased storeProduct and otherwise be null.

However I'm unsure as to whether there exists any better solutions? My schema is complex already so I'd don't want to make it even more complex if it isn't necessary.

**UPDATE:** 
Here's my customer table:

```
Customer
{
    List<ShoppingList> shoppingLists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a new table with something like CustomerID column references to Customer and another column references StoreProduct. Use that to store all the purchased product. I would suggest you to list the Schema related to Customer for this kind of question.

Comment: A customer has a list of ShoppingLists.
Assuming your suggestiong a ProductPurchase would reference: 1 StoreProduct, 1 ShoppingList - is that correct? However I still need to keep track of the quantity of the PurchasedProduct (which ListProduct contains)

Comment: @JensOlsen112 then foreign key to the ListProduct's ID. Each shopping list should have some customer ID right..if so then you can reference to that directly and do a join